# Несколько рабочих столов

Tags: windows

У меня есть системный блок и несколько мониторов

Я хочу чтобы эти оба монитора были подключены к одному системнику, работали от одной мыши и клавиатуры, но на каждом был свой рабочий стол и свои окна.

На сколько реально сделать это?

Операционка windows (любая)

Comment: Здесь просто есть вопрос "Несколько рабочих столов на Windows 7"
Вот я и спрашиваю

Comment: свойства экрана - > растягуть на 2 монитора!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажмите сочетание клавиш Win+P.

Либо поковыряйтесь в настройках: правая кнопка мыши по рабочему столу -> Разрешение экрана.